# drupal 7 changing the action of a webform block in template.php

Tags: drupal-7, action, block, drupal-webform

I have this my template.php

```
function mythemename_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  print($form_id);

  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_61') {
    print ('called');
    $form['#action'] = 'my-new-page';
  }

}
```

And while it is called, it does not change the action of the form. (It is a webform block) is this possible without creating a module?

Answer (score 0):

It actually works fine in template.php but got to pass by reference, so ampersand is needed at the beginning

```
function mythemename_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
```